# Table with fixed column names on win form

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel, sharpdevelop

I am making a win form in C# and in a few places I need to have a table like this:

[image: table]

I'd like to have this on my form with fixed column names but allow the user to enter in data in any of the rows below the first row that contains column names.

I tried to get a TableLayoutPanel to work for this but I couldn't figure out how to control the column names within the table itself.  I am trying to do this in sharpdevelop.

Comment: Why don't just use DataGriwView? As far as I can see, it fit your needs pretty well.

Comment: I had read somewhere that the datagridview is read-only, is that not the case?

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) is the answer you seek.

Comment: @Baub - That is not correct.  You can allow edits or make it read-only; it's completely your call.

Comment: That's true. and if I don't miss remember, it's editable by default, so you may use it...

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to do what you are wanting here.

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Create a new project
3. Create a Winforms application
4. In the 'Toolbox', select 'DataGridView' and add it to your form
5. On the DataGridView (on the form), click the little arrow in the upper-right
6. Select 'Edit Columns'
7. In the dialog, click the 'Add' button
8. Add your column name (**NOTE**: You cannot include punctuation or white space in the name)
9. Under 'Header text', enter the same value you just did in step 8 (you **can** have white space and punctuation here)
10. Click 'Add' once again
11. Notice that now the column is visible in the 'Edit Columns' dialog
12. Repeat for your other columns.

Here is a screen shot of what it should look like:

[image]

Just an FYI, the columns can be edited by default.